# change the matrix when we extend the field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules

Let $M$ be an $F_pC_q$- module represented by the matrix

$$\left( \begin{matrix}
  a & b\\
  c & d
  \end{matrix}\right)$$
i.e., $m_1 g=am_1 + bm_2$ and $m_2g=cm_1 + dm_2$

where g is the generator of $C_q$,  {$m_1, m_2$} is a basis for $M$ and $a,b,c,d \in F_p$ . If we consider $F_p[\xi]$ (the extension of the field $F_p$, where $\xi$ is the primitive $p$th root of unity), how can we represent $M$ in this case? I mean how can we change the matrix when we replace $F_p$ by $F_p[\xi]$?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't say the module is represented by the matrix, you say the generator is represented by the matrix. Do you know what it means to extend the field of scalars of a representation? Why do you think the matrices representing the elements of the group need to change?

Comment: @anon Could you please explain what it means to extend the field of scalars of a representation?

Comment: @anon I think the matrix needs to change because it represents the group $G$ on $M$ and I need $M$ over $F_p[\xi]$. I need an algebraic closed field to study $M$.

Comment: You began your sentence with "I think the matrix needs to change because" but then did not finish the sentence with a reason the matrix would need to change. How about we shift gears. What do you *mean* by the phrase "replace $\Bbb F_p$ by $\Bbb F_p[\xi]$"?

Comment: @anon If $K=F_p[\xi]$, then $M$  is  a $KG$-module. In this case what is the representation of $G$ on $M$? Can we write ${\xi}^n$ as scalars?

Comment: You started out defining $M$ to be a $\Bbb F_p[G]$-module. How are you defining it to be a $\Bbb F_p[\xi][G]$-module now? (There is a natural way to do this, known as extension of scalars, but if that's what you're trying to do, it's important you understand what's going on. For one thing, after extending scalars, you do not end up with the same module - the underlying set of the module becomes bigger.) For instance, say $M=\Bbb F_p$ is one-dimensional and $G$ acts trivially on $M$; you want $M$ to now be a $\Bbb F_q[\xi][G]$ module; if that's true, what happens if you apply $\xi$ to $1\in M$?

Comment: @anon Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. If we apply $\xi$ to $1 \in M=F_p$, it will be $\xi$.

Comment: But $\xi$ is not an element of $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: @anon It will be $1$ if we define $F_p[\xi] \times F_p \rightarrow F_p$ by $(a {\xi}^n, b) \longmapsto ab$.

Comment: Let's suppose that definition of $\Bbb F_p$ as a $\Bbb F_p[\xi]$-module made sense. So $\xi$ acts as the identity map, and $\xi\cdot1=1$. Thus $(\xi-1)\cdot1=0$ and so $0=(\xi-1)^{-1}0=(\xi-1)^{-1}(\xi-1)\cdot1=1\cdot1=1$, i.e. $0=1$, a contradiction. You need to figure out what you're talking about and what you're really asking here.

Comment: @anon Sorry, but I really need to understand the extension of scalars and what about $M$ in this case?

Comment: Actually there is another portion of your question I have overlooked. I assumed you were defining $\xi$ to be a root of unity in a field extension, but *there are no* $p$ *th roots of unity in domains of characteristic* $p$, so what exactly do you mean by $\Bbb F_p[\xi]$? At first blush one might say $\Bbb F_p[X]/(X^p-1)$, but this is not how we adjoin roots of unity with other types of roots, even prime roots in characteristic zero! (e.g. $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ is not the same as $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^p-1)$.)

Comment: @anon Sorry, $\xi$ is the $q$ th root of unity

Comment: You still need to explain what you mean by replacing $\Bbb F_p$ by $\Bbb F_p[\xi]$. Extension of scalars will also make the underlying set of the module bigger; do you understand this? Do you want a crash course on extension of scalars, or do *you* mean something in particular when you use the phrase?

Comment: @anon I would appreciate it if you tell me how I can understand extension of scalars in general, so I can help myself in any particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$ and $L/K$ is a field extension. Let $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ be a basis for the space (assume it's finite-dimensional for convenience). Then every element looks like

$$a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n $$

for some scalars $a_1,\cdots,a_n\in K$. To add two vectors, we merely add them coefficientwise, and to multiply by a scalar $c$ we multiply each scalar by $c$. Intuitively then to extend scalars to $L$, we are constructing a new vector space $V_L$ comprised of formal sums $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$ where now we have scalars $a_1,\cdots,a_n\in L$ (not just in $K$). It should be clear how $V_L$ is a vector space over $L$ and how the underlying set of $V_L$ is bigger than $V$ (there are sum in $V_L$ that are not in $V$; just pick a sum of the $v_i$s with coefficients not in $K$).

Suppose $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation. What is the matrix representing it, with respect to the basis we're using? For $i=1,\cdots,n$ we can apply $T$ to $v_i$ and then write the result as a sum:

$$T(v_1)=a_{1,1}v_1+a_{2,1}v_2+\cdots+a_{n,1}v_n $$

$$T(v_2)=a_{1,2}v_1+a_{2,2}v_2+\cdots+a_{n,2}v_n $$

$$\cdots\cdots$$

$$T(v_n)=a_{1,n}v_1+a_{2,n}v_2+\cdots+a_{n,n}v_n $$

for some scalars $a_{i,j}\in K$. These numbers determine $T$; to apply $T$ to any other vector, simply use the distributive property as $T(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n)=c_1T(v_1)+\cdots c_nT(v_n)$. Using this rule we can define a linear map $T_L:V_L\to V_L$ which does the same thing to basis vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ as written above, and to apply $T_L$ to any other vector in $V_L$ just use the distributive property.

If we rewrite sums $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$ as column vectors $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)^t$ then $T$'s matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\ a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & a_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}.$$

For example, applying the matrix to $(1,0,\cdots,0)^t$ yields $(a_{1,1},a_{2,1},\cdots,a_{n,1})^t$. By construction, the matrix of $T_L$ is the same matrix, because we are using the same basis and $T_L$ acts the exact same on the basis vectors.

Notice our construction of $V_L$ depended on using a basis for $V$. What about if we have a module that doesn't have a basis though? We need a basis-free way of doing extension of scalars. The idea is that we must be able to "pretend multiply" vectors in $V$ by scalars in $L$: the way to achieve "pretend multiplication" in a rigorous, formal manner is to use the tensor product.

We define $L\otimes_K V$ to be the collection of all sums of the symbols $l\otimes v$, and then impose some conditions: distributivity on the left and the right of $\otimes$ (so it works like multiplication) and the associativity rule $lk\otimes v=l\otimes kv$ for any $l\in L,k\in K,v\in V$.

Clearly this is a vector space over $L$ (to multiply by a scalar in $L$, simply multiply the scalars in front of all of the $\otimes$ symbols). If $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then $\{1\otimes v_1,\cdots,1\otimes v_n\}$ is a basis for $L\otimes_KV$, and by thinking of $1\otimes v_i$ as $v_i$ we see that $L\otimes_KV$ is the same as $V_L$. Now suppose $R$ is a ring and $M$ is an $R$-module. (Recall vector spaces are simply modules over fields.) If $S$ is a bigger ring containing $R$, we can turn $M$ into an $S$-module via the tensor product as $S\otimes_R M$ in the same exact way.